# Why does -Verbose disable the use of $ErrorActionPreference?

Tags: powershell

Let's take this script:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try
{
  echo "ErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference"
  Copy-Item  "this_is_a_bad_path" 
  Write-Host "Did not catch error"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Caught Error"
}
```

This works as expected with this output:

```
ErrorActionPreference = Stop
Caught Error
```

But if I add `-verbose` to the line, giving me `Copy-Item -verbose "this_is_a_bad_path"`, the `$ErrorActionPrefrence` is no longer used and I get this output:

```
ErrorActionPreference = Stop
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\porter.bassett\this_is_a_bad_path' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\porter.bassett\dot.ps1:7 char:3
+   Copy-Item -verbose "this_is_a_bad_path"
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\porter...s_is_a_bad_path:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Did not catch error
```

In order to get it to work properly with `-verbose` turned, on, I have to add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the line giving me `Copy-Item -verbose "this_is_a_bad_path" -ErrorAction Stop`

Why can't I rely on `$ErrorActionPreference` when using `-Verbose`?

Comment: After quick pick with ILSpy, it looks like intentional behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to think of any possible reason for making it do that.  So far, I'm failing.

Comment: 'tis always nice when the answer to *my* google-searched-for question is already in the question title itself! :-) Thanks a bunch for a well formulated title :-)

Comment: There's hope: the [issue has been reported](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2247).

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature/bug in PowerShell as also discussed on Technet here: [Verbose common parameter disables ErrorActionPreference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3308eee2-2ac9-4648-838a-c06f3bdc24de/verbose-common-parameter-disables-erroractionpreference?forum=winserverpowershell).

This feature/bug is there in PowerShell 4 and the latest version 5 as well.

Comment: A "better" discussion link: [Adding -Verbose to a Cmdlet Prevents Script From Terminating on Error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/b76eccae-4484-43ec-a3dc-d4bc581124c2/adding-verbose-to-a-cmdlet-prevents-script-from-terminating-on-error?forum=winserverpowershell)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't have a *why*, but this [triple face palm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjcrV.jpg) issue (well, at least IMHO), is still active in the open source PS code:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/02b5f357a20e6dee9f8e60e3adb9025be3c94490/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs#L3207 :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// ErrorAction tells the command what to do when an error occurs
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.Management.Automation.ExtendedTypeSystemException">
    /// (get-only) An error occurred accessing $ErrorAction.
    /// </exception>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is a common parameter via class CommonParameters.
    /// </remarks>
    internal ActionPreference ErrorAction
    {
        get
        {
            // Setting CommonParameters.ErrorAction has highest priority
            if (IsErrorActionSet)
                return _errorAction;

            // Debug takes preference over Verbose
            if (Debug)
                return ActionPreference.Inquire;
            if (Verbose)
                return ActionPreference.Continue; *** WTF!?! ***

            // fall back to $ErrorAction
            if (!_isErrorActionPreferenceCached)
            {
                bool defaultUsed = false;
                _errorAction = Context.GetEnumPreference<ActionPreference>(SpecialVariables.ErrorActionPreferenceVarPath, _errorAction, out defaultUsed);
                _isErrorActionPreferenceCached = true;
            }
            return _errorAction;
        }
```

Comment: ++ for the sleuthing. There's hope: the [issue has been reported](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2247). Generally, it's worth reporting issues at the [PowerShell's GitHub repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) - the maintainers of PowerShell and the community are very active there.

Answer (score -2):

Your best bet is to specify erroraction for every command in your module.

`write-host foo -ErrorAction Stop`

Updated: this blog post is helpful. It explains how global var inheritance causes the observed behavior.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/26/weekend-scripter-access-powershell-preference-variables/

Comment: That - cumbersome - workaround is already mentioned in the question itself. The question is about _why this is needed_.

Comment: Updated my answer. It is still cumbersome, but at least it works. I am interested to know if there is a better answer around.

Comment: The OP is aware of the workaround and mentions _not_ wanting to use it, because it is cumbersome. The article you link to is interesting, but unrelated to the problem at hand (it deals with modules not inheriting the caller's preference variables). By contrast, the essence of this question is: With `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in effect, why does using `-Verbose` in a given call deactivate it (for that call)?